# Including attributes from a join model in a seperate form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, has-many-through

I have an association setup where a `Track` can belong to multiple `Releases` through `ReleaseTracks`:

```
class Release < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :release_tracks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tracks, through: :release_tracks
end

class ReleaseTrack < ApplicationRecord
  # disc, side, number
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track

  belongs_to :album
end

class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :release_tracks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :releases, through: :release_tracks

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:release_id, :album_id]
end
```

As you can see, the `ReleaseTrack` has three attributes `disc, side, number` to correctly identify the correct placement for a track on any specific release. I was wondering in the instance of creating a new track in a release form, how could I also save those three attributes?